# Backing up emails on Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Outlook keeps asking me to archive my emails, the last time I did that it moved all my emails to the archive (deleted them from Outlook). I had to go to the archive an put them back into each folder manually.

How can I archive and keep a copy of all my emails as I need access to them on a daily basis, but I'd like to know that they have been saved somewhere so that I have a back up.

Comment: First thing i thought of is powershell script that can copy the email object to two separate folders at the same time. This is not difficult. I use this for moving emails (rules) - example script: http://wondershell.blogspot.de/2013/03/outlook-rules-with-powershell-upgraded.html . But i think there is a neatier solution - copy all of them to newly created PST file. Unmount PST file. Close outlook. Copy PST to archive destination. Now you got PST in two location. Mount one of them to Outlook and move your emails back to Inbox. Still, with powershell script you could easily automate this proces

Comment: Why don't you just add the archive file to the list of accounts that are displayed.  You still have access to this archive file.  You then can use services like Dropbox and others to keep cloud backups.